# get cc_type value

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-gateway

How could I get the value (text, not the code) of `cc_type` in my payment gateway model?

In payment gateway model for `authorize()` and `capture()` I do get `$payment` object from which I do get `cc_type` as `$payment->getCcType()` but it returns the code for the `cc_type` how could I get the value of the code. e.g., it return **VI** for the **VISA**. So, how could I get **VISA** from the `$payment` or `$payment->getCcType()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code in my payment model works fine:

```
$sType = $payment->getCcType();
$aType = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getCcTypes();
if (isset($aType[$sType])) {
    $sName = $aType[$sType];
}
else {
    $sName = Mage::helper('payment')->__('N/A');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is an array with the correspondence between the cc type code and the label.
There is one for example in authorize.net.

If your payment method works in a similar way with the authorize.net then your can do this.

```
$ccType = $payment->getCcType();
$paymentInstance = $payment->getMethodInstance();
$ccTypes = $method->getConfigData('cctypes');

if (isset($ccTypes[$ccType])) {
    $label = $ccTypes[$ccType];
}
else {
    $label = ''; //not a valid cc type
}
```

Comment: yes. it is the array which is default in magento cc type. your code seems to be promising.. let me check

Comment: not working. still getting the code. in `$method->getConfigData('cctypes');` should there be `'cctypes'`?

Comment: Check what are the values returned by `$method->getConfigData('cctypes');`. Like I said, this could work if your payment method is similar to authorize.net. There is a chance this won't work for you.

Comment: `AE,VI,MC,DI` is returned. my payment method extends magento's payment method cc

Comment: how do magento ables to get the value from the code in admin sales > order?